# removing .dat file only while creating the new file

Tags: java, file

I am stuck up in an odd situation, actually i had a job which creates the file in a separate folder and the job run daily so every day it
creates the file in that folder and the file is with .dat extension along with it's zip file .

now let say if the job run today it will create two file in that folder and the next day I want that zip file of the 
previous day to be remain there in that folder but the .dat file should be get deleted before the .dat file of present day get created , i have write the code but it is not happening as I want please advise how to achieve this

```
File file = new File(ilePath + s); //filepath contains the location where the file will be get created and s contain the filename

                for (File f : new File(mcrpFilePath).listFiles()) { // For each
                                                                    // dat
                    // file in
                    // the
                    // directory,
                    // delete
                    // it.

                    if (f.isFile()
                            && file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".dat")) {
                        f.delete();
                    }
                }
                file.createNewFile();
```

Now please advise how can I have the previous zip files in that folder but the .dat file of previous day to be get deleted

Comment: As far as I understand your code does delete the old an creates the new file. What exactly does not work as you need it? Please provide more details on the situation. Thank you.

Comment: @jboi yeah correct , I want the zip files to be there and only .dat file to be get deleted while the new .dat file is created by my code

Comment: @henry rite now it delete all the files which should not happen it should not delete the zip files

Answer (score 3):

change

```
file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".dat")
```

to

```
f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".dat")
```

Comment: That's one of those bugs you look at for hours and don't see it :-)